# MediaRecorder Camera Xamarin C# Wont Start On emulator or real Device PERMISSIONS seem to be the ERROR

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera, mediarecorder

Hi All having real issues starting camcorder natively, I have applied all permissions still .start() does not work.

I have had success with MediaPicker for recording videos, but this does not allow to set quality of video if phones interface does not allow.

```
var outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myvideooutputfile.mp4");

            MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            //correctCamera();
            //if (camera != null)
            //    mediaRecorder.SetCamera(camera);

        //mediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        mediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
        mediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
        //mediaRecorder.SetVideoSize(1280, 720);
        mediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
        //mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(outputFile))
                System.IO.File.Delete(outputFile);
            System.IO.File.Create(outputFile);

            //CamcorderProfile camProf = CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.Q720p);
            //mediaRecorder.SetProfile(camProf);
            mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(outputFile);
            mediaRecorder.Prepare();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
            mediaRecorder.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

exception thrown message is only 'start failed', the stack is:

```
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <2e109281f9514c53b44688fd4549adb2>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <2e109281f9514c53b44688fd4549adb2>:0 
  at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Start () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-31/mcw/Android.Media.MediaRecorder.cs:2392 
  at RECOmobile.Views.RecoveryJobPage.Take_Video_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0008f] in C:\Users\Paul\source\repos\RECO\RECOmobile\RECOmobile\Views\RecoveryJobPage.xaml.cs:330 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:104)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

this is a screenshot of the 'mediaRecorder' object after prepare has succeeded and before start fails:

[image: object]

DEVICE LOGS:
This seems to show some sort of permissions error even though I have now put in the SYSTEM_CAMERA permission into the manifest!:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
10-10 14:27:48.874  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 539 AlarmManager    Alarms must either supply a PendingIntent or an AlarmReceiver
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 Camera2-Parameters  Error finding static metadata entry 'android.distortionCorrection.availableModes' (1b0001)
10-10 14:27:54.342  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 302 HwBinder:302_3  type=1400 audit(0.0:1783): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1073 scontext=u:r:hal_camera_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-10 14:27:54.347  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.347  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 libc    Access denied finding property "ro.camera.res.fmq.size"
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 FMQ grantorIdx must be less than 3
10-10 14:27:54.344  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   302 libc    Access denied finding property "ro.camera.req.fmq.size"
10-10 14:27:54.338  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2ClientBase   Camera 0: Opened. Client: com.companyname.recomobile (PID 437, UID 10156)
10-10 14:27:54.338  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 CameraService   disconnect: Disconnected client for camera 0 for PID 437
10-10 14:27:54.336  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera3-Device  disconnectImpl: X
10-10 14:27:54.306  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera3-Device  disconnectImpl: E
10-10 14:27:54.295  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 Camera2Client   notifyError: Error condition 0 reported by HAL, requestId -1
10-10 14:27:54.295  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   411 CameraService   CameraService::connect evicting conflicting client for camera ID 0
10-10 14:27:54.293  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 CameraService   CameraService::connect call (PID 19443 "com.companyname.recomobile", camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 411 ServiceManager  Permission failure: android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA from uid=1013 pid=437
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder Using default video fps 30
10-10 14:27:54.292  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 MPEG4Writer PreAllocation enabled
10-10 14:27:50.991  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:50.991  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 chatty  uid=1000(system) Binder:539_2 identical 1 line
10-10 14:27:50.990  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:50.990  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 SoundTriggerMiddlewareLogging   setCaptureState[this=com.android.server.soundtrigger_middleware.SoundTriggerMiddlewareImpl@d9fa08f, caller=1041/331](false)
10-10 14:27:50.787  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder stop while neither recording nor paused
10-10 14:27:50.787  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 331 AudioFlinger    session id 201 not found for pid 19443
10-10 14:27:50.777  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   447 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   Destruction - bufferpool2 0x7b03df1d0068 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 1, 0% recycled; transfers: 0, 0% unfetched
10-10 14:27:50.776  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   447 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   bufferpool2 0x7b03df1d0068 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/1 (recycle/alloc) - 0/0 (fetch/transfer)
10-10 14:27:50.775  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   Destruction - bufferpool2 0xe58c6628 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 5, 0% recycled; transfers: 0, 0% unfetched
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Verbose 447 C2Store unloading dll
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 BufferPoolAccessor2.0   bufferpool2 0xe58c6628 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 0/0 (fetch/transfer)
10-10 14:27:50.774  pixel_5_-_api_30    Verbose 447 C2Store in ~ComponentModule
10-10 14:27:50.773  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 hw-BpHwBinder   onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
10-10 14:27:50.772  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 CCodecBufferChannel [c2.android.amrnb.encoder#143] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
10-10 14:27:50.772  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 chatty  uid=1013(media) codec_looper identical 2 lines
10-10 14:27:50.771  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   437 CCodecBufferChannel [c2.android.amrnb.encoder#143] MediaCodec discarded an unknown buffer
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder stop while neither recording nor paused
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 StagefrightRecorder Failed to set stopTime 5757715322 us for Audio
10-10 14:27:50.770  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 AMessage    failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
10-10 14:27:49.656  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   539 WifiNative  Scan result ready event
10-10 14:27:49.656  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   539 WifiNl80211Manager  Scan result ready event
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2-Parameters  Camera 0: Disabling ZSL mode
10-10 14:27:54.351  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    411 Camera2-Parameters  initialize: allowZslMode: 0 slowJpegMode 0
10-10 14:27:54.342  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 302 HwBinder:302_3  type=1400 audit(0.0:1784): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1073 scontext=u:r:hal_camera_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-10 14:27:54.365  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 OMXClient   IOmx service obtained
10-10 14:27:54.366  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    442 OMXMaster   makeComponentInstance(OMX.google.h264.encoder) in android.hardwar process
10-10 14:27:54.368  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 MediaCodec  MediaCodec will operate in async mode
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 OMXUtils    do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  setupAVCEncoderParameters with [profile: Baseline] [level: Level41]
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  [OMX.google.h264.encoder] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring.
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  [OMX.google.h264.encoder] cannot encode HDR static metadata. Ignoring.
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  setupVideoEncoder succeeded
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance setConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    437 ACodec  codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 OMXUtils    do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361
10-10 14:27:54.369  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance getConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigLatency(0x6f800005)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.370  pixel_5_-_api_30    Error   442 OMXNodeInstance getConfig(0xe9c00710:google.h264.encoder, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: Undefined(0x80001001)
10-10 14:27:54.374  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 ResourceManagerService  Ignoring request to add new resource entry with value <= 0
10-10 14:27:54.376  pixel_5_-_api_30    Debug   442 SoftAVCEnc  Params width 176 height 144 level 41 colorFormat 0
10-10 14:27:54.380  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    331 AudioFlinger    AudioFlinger's thread 0x79c44956a040 tid=19677 ready to run
10-10 14:27:54.382  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:54.383  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 chatty  uid=1000(system) Binder:539_2 identical 1 line
10-10 14:27:54.384  pixel_5_-_api_30    Info    539 system_server   oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
10-10 14:27:54.386  pixel_5_-_api_30    Warning 437 AudioRecord createRecord_l(62): Server adjusted notificationFrames from 1024 to 122 for frameCount 2048
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @Jason thank you for reply, I have edited with the thrown exception

Comment: Are you testing on a physical device?

Comment: Using emulator at the moment, but with mediapicker attempts emulator camera has been working @Jason

Comment: From the docs: “ note: Currently, MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator. “

Comment: Ah... I see :( will try on real device in morning thank you for your help @Jason

Comment: Hi @Jason  I have tested this morning on a real device (galaxy s22 ultra), but still get the 'start failed' error

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this problem. I tested on the official sample :[Example_WorkingWithAudio](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/Example_WorkingWithAudio) and modified code  [RecordAudio.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/main/Example_WorkingWithAudio/Example_WorkingWithAudio/RecordAudio.cs) to yours, but I couldn't reproduce this problem after clicking the `Start` Button.

Comment: I have 0 idea what im doing wrong :( same experience on emulator and real phone

Comment: However I am trying VIDEO/Camcorder option not just audio @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Ive also just tried to download and run that example but VS is erroring saying I dont have API level 19.....EVEN THOUGH IN THE SDK API 19 DOESNT EVEN EXIST!?!?!?! this shouldnt be this difficult

Comment: UPDATE ive also just tried that solution code for just audio and it does not error. only trying to record video errors on start() @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: `only trying to record video errors on start()`  On what device are you testing?

Comment: Hi ive said it above a few times, I've tired the api31 emulator and two real devices samsung galaxy s22 ultra and doogee s100

Comment: For this, you can check thread: [Xamarin- how to record video and save it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115457/xamarin-how-to-record-video-and-save-it-to-a-file).